# How to load initial_data (fixture) after migration and not after syncdb?

Tags: python, django, migration, fixtures, django-syncdb

I have a `bootstrap` script that performs `syncdb` and `migrate`:

```
import settings
from django.core.management import setup_environ, call_command

setup_environ(settings)                                         # Setting up the env settings
call_command('syncdb', migrate=True, interactive=False)         # Sync the database
```

**Pre-Requisites:**

- `django-south` for migrations.

**Process happening:**

- `initial_data` fixture contains data for a model that is created by migrations.
- `syncdb` is executed it creates all the tables except for those apps where migrations exists.
- Post `syncdb` it tries to load `initial_data` and raises **error** of db not found because the table for app with migrations were not created by syncdb.  [ **Problem** ]
- Then it performs migration which creates the db.
- Post `migration` it automatically loads `initial_data` successfully this time.

**Problem:**

- How can I get rid of the `error`, when it tries to load fixture for the table that is not yet created ?
- Can I edit the above script in a way so that it loads `initial_data` only after performing the `migration` ?

Comment: That's one of the reasons south is not part of django i guess :)

Comment: Seems like.. but if it would have been then this problem would have been addressed in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could disable loading initial data when syncdb:

```
call_command('syncdb', load_initial_data=False, interactive=False)
call_command('migrate', interactive=False)
```

From the source code of syncdb.py:

```
# Stealth option -- 'load_initial_data' is used by the testing setup                                                               
# process to disable initial fixture loading.                                                                                      
load_initial_data = options.get('load_initial_data', True)
```

Comment: How can we disable `load_initial_data` when running syncdb from the command line ?

Comment: use the `--no-initial-data` switch (also available for `migrate` command)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can solve this:

1. Exclude the apps from the initial data dump by just calling the apps you want to populate data for
2. Could try this library https://github.com/davedash/django-fixture-magic
3. You could write a custom management command to populate the models you require
4. You can also use data migration that comes with south http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/part3.html

Personally I would go with either 1 or 3. With the first point, store the fixtures individually in each app under a fixtures folder. However, this is pain to update if your models change. So writing a custom management command might be the most painless.